# Iteratively applying a user written function to pairs stored in two different data frame colums

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, functional-programming

Consider this data:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10),
                   ID = 1:200,
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var2 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

Individuals (each with a unique `ID`) were randomly sampled from 20 different populations, which are denoted by the grouping variable `Loc`. Measurements of 6 different variables (each `var.`) were taken on each `ID`. I am using the `vegan` package to do `anosim()`. I want to do pairwise comparisons between each possible pair of `Loc`s in `dat1`. I wrote this function to do the pairwise comparisons:

```r
library(vegan)
anosim.res <- data.frame()
pwc.anosim <- function(g1, g2){#g1 and g2 are the groups
  dat <- dplyr::filter(dat1, Loc == g1 | Loc == g2)
  vars <- dat[,3:8]#get the variables
  vars <- scale(vars)#scale them
  dmat <- vegdist(vars, method = "euclidian")#calculate a distance matrix 
  res <- anosim(dmat, dat$Loc)#perform the anosim between the two Locs
  out <- data.frame(Group1 = g1,
                    Group2 = g2,
                    R = res$statistic,
                    p = res$signif)#make a column for each of the groups, and get the stats
  anosim.res <<- rbind(anosim.res,out)#store out in the external data frame 
} 
#this will be to store the results:
anosim.res<-data.frame()
#try it with 2 random Locs a and b: 
pwc.anosim(g1 = "a", g2 = "b")
```

This works fine when I specify the `Loc`s individually. Now I want to loop through all possible combinations of the `Loc`s, so I make the object `Pairs`:

```r
Pairs <-expand.grid(unique(dat1$Loc),unique(dat1$Loc))
```

I thought I would be able to loop through each pair of groups stored in `Loc`s like this:

```
for(i in Pairs[,1]){
  for(j in Pairs[,2]){
    pwc.anosim(g1=i, g2=j)
  }
}
#or:
for(i in Pairs$Var1){
  for(j in Pairs$Var2){
    pwc.anosim(g1=i, g2=j)
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```r
Error in data.frame(Group1 = g1, Group2 = g2, R = res$statistic, p = res$signif) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use this function on each pair of `Loc`s?

Comment: Are `Pairs[,1]` and `Pairs[,2]` factors? If so, would it matter?

Comment: @Henry Yes but I don't think it would matter: `Pairs` was created to show all possible pairwise comparisons between the levels of `levels(dat1$Loc)`. `Loc` is a grouping variable that represent locations from which the `ID`s were sampled (and of course `var`s are the measurements).

Comment: `pwc.anosim('a', 'a')` returns `Error in anosim(dmat, dat$Loc) : there should be more than one class level`

Comment: @RonakShah I believe I see what you are saying, how can I specify "all pairwise combinations" (like what I was trying to do in making the object `Pairs`, without including the constants (e.g., we wouldn't want to compare `Loc == a' with `Loc == a`). Is that what you are saying is producing the error?

Comment: The first row in `Pairs` dataframe is `a`, `a` which when passed to `pwc.anosim` function returns an error as shown in my earlier comment.

Comment: @RonakShah I see, would you have created the object `Pairs` differently, or would you just remove duplicates from `Pairs` (as I created it)? If so, how would you remove the duplicates from `Pairs`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already enumerated every combination of pairs by calling `expand.grid`, you don't need a nested loop - you can just do a single loop over `Pairs`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Pairs)) {
    pwc.anosim2(g1=Pairs[i, 1], g2=Pairs[i, 2])
}
```

Or, more concisely,

```
purrr::walk2(Pairs[[1]], Pairs[[2]], pwc.anosim2)
```

Be sure that `pwc.anosim2` can handle factor inputs, since `expand.grid` produces a data.frame of factors by default, including in R 4.0.0+.

Comment: the 2 after `pwc.anosim` was a typo, I fixed this in the question. However, when I try this with the regular `pwc.anosim` I still get the same error: `Error in data.frame(Group1 = g1, Group2 = g2, R = res$statistic, p = res$signif) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`